# HTML5 strange rendering in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, height

My site body is shown strangely in Firefox. The wrapper div is ignoring the height of it's contents. And the images for my video player are ignoring the CSS rules applied to them.
My site: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/video.html

This is what it looks like:
[image]

CSS:

```
#controls img{
    height:100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
#wrapper{
    max-width: 850px;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box; /*means this is a box with children inside*/
    -moz-box-orient:vertical;
    -moz-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; /*allows site to grow or shrink 1 = flex 0 = statix*/
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

    z-index: 1;
}
#body_div{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    color:#000000;
    margin-top: 190px;
}
```

BODY HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="body_div">

        <div id="dimPlayer" class="dim" onclick="playPause()"></div>
        <div id="video_container">
            <video id="trailers" poster="images/poster/poster.jpg">
                <source src="media/vLast.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="media/vLast.webm" type="video/webm">
                <track id="mytrack" label="English Subtitles" src="subtitles.vtt" srclang="en" />
            </video>
            <nav>
               <div id="controls" class="cAnimated fadeInUp fadeInDown">
                    <div id="defaultBar">
                        <div id="progressBar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <button id="playButton"><img src="images/icons/play.png" /></button>
                    <button id="vol" onclick="showSlider()"><img src="images/icons/vol.png" /></button>      
                    <button id="containSlider"> 
                                <input type="range" id="vSlider" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5"/></button>
                    <div id='containTime'><span id='timeDisplay'>0:00</span><span>/</span><span id='durationDisplay'>0:00</span></div>
                    <button id="full"><img src="images/icons/full.png" /></button>
                    <button id="mute"><img src="images/icons/mute.png" /></button>
                    <button id="cc">CC</button>

               </div> 
               <div id="playlist" class="animated fadeInRight">
                    <div class="thumb" id="tb1"><img src="images/thumbnails/TbGow.jpg" onClick="changeTrailer('media/vGow')"/></div>
                    <div class="thumb" id="tb2"><img src="images/thumbnails/TbLast.jpg" onClick="changeTrailer('media/vLast')"/></div>
                    <div class="thumb" id="tb3"><img src="images/thumbnails/TbTwo.jpg" onClick="changeTrailer('media/vTwo')"/></div>
               </div>
            </nav>
        </div>        
        <aside id="sidebar">
            <div id="side_events">
                <h1>Upcoming Releases</h1> 
                 <ul id="events">
                    <li><a href="http://www.t3.com/news/half-life-3-rumours-trailer-news-release-date-and-screenshots" target="_blank">Half-Life 3 Release: <time>04/01/13</time></a></li>
                    <li><a  href="http://www.examiner.com/article/borderlands-2-writer-talks-about-possible-borderlands-3-plot-points" target="_blank">Borderlands 3 Release: <time>05/29/13</time></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.e3expo.com/" target="_blank">E3 2013 Starting: <time>08/11/13</time></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.theverge.com/2013/2/1/3942142/new-sony-playstation-2013" target="_blank">Playstation 4 Release: <time>08/31/13</time></a> </li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.theverge.com/2012/1/25/2731888/next-xbox" target="_blank">Xbox 720 Release: <time>09/01/13</time></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="side_trailer"><a href="video.html"><img src="images/thumbnails/TbTwo.jpg" /></a></div>

            <div id="side_advert"></div>                     
        </aside>

    </section>

    <footer id="footer">
        &copy; Copyright  by SimKessy
    </footer>
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use Flex Boxes but haven't quite understood the syntax, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes - the property is display : flex, not box (with display : -moz-flex and -webkit-flex for cross-browser compatibility). The flex property also needs to be applied to the children, not the parent. I suspect flex-direction is the property you are trying to use box-orient for. The flexbox spec has changed several times, you might have been using an outdated tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change display: -moz-box; on #wrapper to display:block;.

```
#wrapper{
   max-width: 850px;
   display: block;
   ...
```

Comment: I have never heard of a css property value -moz-box. Just box should work the same too, so you can get rid of the -webkit- one too.

Comment: Yes.. also the -moz- and -webkit- properties are only interpreted on Mozilla and WebKit based browsers, all other browsers will ignore them. Generic fallbacks should be defined.

Comment: Needs a little adjustment on your footer too, it seems, but I'm not sure how you want that to look. The blue 'ad' image is not showing up in FF.

Comment: Changing #side_advert height to 200px instead of 30% makes everything look good to me. Add a background-repeat:no-repeat maybe too.

Comment: Change the display to block causes the contents of the page to move up  and behind the nav/header (chrome). In firefox, the footer moves up and down with the page unlike chrome where it always stays at the bottom. The side advert change worked though. Thanks

Comment: Any reason why the video player images won't resize in firefox?

Answer (score -2):

In order to stretch a block element to the height of it's child elements, you need to add `float: left;` to that block element, in your case the `#wrapper`.

The images' styles apply just fine. When hovering the lower area of the video, the image bar is shown with `opacity: 0.3`;

Comment: If i apply float left to the wrapper wont my page no longer be centered

Comment: But the height: auto is applied correctly. Sorry, but you'll have to correct the consequential errors then.

Comment: im not sure i know what that means

Comment: sorry if i didnt put it clear. it means that you'll have to work the css of the wrongly positioned items out again if you want the #wrapper to stretch it's height automatically.

Comment: Block level elements will automatically stretch to the height of their children unless the child elements are floated or have a position property (such as absolute) that takes the element out of document flow. It is not necessary to float an element in order for it to match the height of children.